# Show there exists $\gamma$ such that $\int f|g|=\gamma \int |g|$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I have been going through a course in measure theory and integration. Got stuck in one intermediate step of the proof.It says that-

If $g$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is measurable and there exist $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha\le f(x)\le\beta$

Then there exists $\gamma\in [\alpha, \beta]$ such that

$$\int f \lvert g\rvert dx=\gamma \int \lvert g\rvert~dx$$

---

This has been my attempt.

Since $\alpha$ $\le$ $f$ $\le$ $\beta$

Therefore $\lvert f\rvert$ $\le$ $\delta$ where $\delta$ = max{$\lvert \alpha\rvert$, $\lvert \beta\rvert$}

Therefore $\lvert f\rvert$$\lvert g\rvert$ $\le$ $\delta$$\lvert g\rvert$

From here can I conclude that $f$ $\lvert g\rvert$ is integrable? (This is my main doubt)

Comment: If $g$ is integrable and $|fg| \le \delta|g|$ then $fg$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the comparison test for Lebesgue integrability or proved as follows.

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the set of all nonnegative, bounded measurable functions of finite  support such that $0 \leqslant h \leqslant |f||g|$. Since $|f||g| \leqslant \delta|g|$ and $\delta |g|$ is integrable we have by monotonicity of the integral,

$$\int h \leqslant \int \delta |g| \implies \int|f||g| = \sup_{h \in \mathcal{H}}\int h \leqslant \int \delta |g| < +\infty,$$

and, thus,  $|f||g|$ is integrable. Since $f^+|g|, f^-|g| \leqslant |f||g|$ it follows that $f|g| = (f^+-f^-)|g|$ is integrable.